# How to send a series of HTTP POST requests in parallel?

Tags: python-3.x, http

I am using Python 3.

I need to send POST HTTP requests in parallel. I see a lot of examples showing how to process a list of GET calls.

The requests are to different URLs with different POST bodies.

Any hints on how this can be done?

Comment: tried using `threading` and `requests` module? Seems like the easiest way to do it.

Comment: how would this work using aiohttp module

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `threading` and `requests` modules. Threading is to run the post requests in parallel and requests to put the post request.

Here's how I would do it:

```py
import threading
import requests

def target_func(url, post_body):
  requests.post(url, json=post_body)

threads = []

json_1 = {
  # json data here
}
json_2 = {
  # json data here
}

threads.append(threading.Thread(target=target_func, args=["url here", json_1]))
threads.append(threading.Thread(target=target_func, args=["url here", json_2]))

# copy and paste for how many different requests you want

for thread in threads:
  thread.start()
  thread.join()
```

Comment: I see that working but how do I get my hands on the responses of the HTTP POST calls?

Comment: I'm not too sure about that actually